# MySQL normalization dilemma challenge

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I am moving from an unnormalized table to normalized, but I got confused in the following situation:

```
MovieID(pk) | MovieTitle
--------------------- 
1           | Imagination
2           | Creativity
3           | Bodyguard


ActorID(pk) | Name
--------------------- 
25          | John
26          | Charlie
27          | George
28          | Lincoln

MovieID(ck) | ActorID(ck)     <---- Indexed Table
--------------------- 
1           | 25
1           | 26
2           | 25
2           | 28
3           | 26
3           | 27
3           | 28
```

Till here, everything should be fine, but then each actor has a role (or more) in the movie.

My solution is:

Adding the following table:

```
RoleID(pk)  | RoleTitle
--------------------- 
84          | Doctor
85          | Lawyer
86          | Farmer
87          | Judge
88          | Farmer John
89          | The Police
90          | Policeman
91          | Mother of Johny
92          | Prisoner
93          | Doctor
```

And modifying the indexed table to this:

```
MovieID(ck) | ActorID(ck) | RoleID(ck)     <---- Indexed Table
------------------------------------------ 
1           | 25          | 84
1           | 25          | 85
1           | 26          | 86
2           | 25          | 87
2           | 28          | 88
3           | 26          | 89
3           | 27          | 90
3           | 28          | 91
3           | 28          | 92
3           | 28          | 93
```

But then, what's the point of creating a new table, with values repeating, like in our case: RoleID: 84 and 93, and knowing that each row will be used only one time by one actor?

Can someone help me with this concern?

I can give more details, if it's not clear.

Comment: There's not much point!

Comment: Why are you duplicating Role Tititles?

Comment: I wouldn't normalize further and just stay with indexed table but with added columns "role". My reason: roles in movies should be descriptive... meaning a "doctor"(generic which could be implemented by what you did) role is different from "crazy doctor" or "doctor with beautiful wife"...

Comment: @barudo, what If i try to add multiple roles?

Comment: @barudo, If I keep only 2 keys as Composite keys, than I can not assign multiple roles, so the solution would be is to add a new column "role" as you said, but to make it part of composite key too. Is that a good idea?

Comment: I'm with @barudo you don't need a roles table. Add role information to the indexed table, the roleID seems superfluous. You can assign multiple roles by making multiple entries (rows), which you have to do with the other solution also.

Comment: @maraca, should I make the role part of composite key too?

Comment: @maraca, that's what I mean, I will make a composite key out of: movieID, actorID and roleTitle.

Comment: @maraca, If i dont do the roleTitle part of composite key, I will not be able to set more than one role to an actor in a movie.

Comment: @PHPLovere Ah yes, you can make (MovieID, ActorID, Role) the key, but only if an actor doesn't play two doctors in the same movie (they have to be called doctor1 and doctor2 then or something).

Comment: @maraca, will the Role column cause any performance issues, if yes, is there any better methods than this?

Comment: @PHPLovere it depends what kind of queries you have especially the joins. E.g. if you want to count the number of movies actor X played in, then you have to do a distinct with 1 table, if you have 2 tables ([movieID, actorID] and [movieID, actorID, role] then you can use the first one to join "naturally" without distinct in the count.

Comment: simply put: if you almost always need the movie, actors and roles together then put them in 1 table, if you are rarely interested in the roles use 2 tables, makes the queries easier.

Answer (score 1):

The solution would be to remove Roles table, and add to the indexed table the roleTitle. To be able to add more role titles, this should be primary key with the others in the indexed table.

Answer (score 0):

A movie contains roles played by actors. So I see these tables (primary key is bold):

- movie (**movie_no**, movie_title)
- actor (**actor_no**, actor_name)
- movie_role (**movie_no, role_name**, actor_no)